# How to make delay after drawing a line?

Tags: c#, wpf

I working on a wpf c# app and i want after drawing a line,have 1 second delay witout blocking UI.

my drawing function is here:

```
    private void DrawLine(int serviceTime, string lineName)
    {
        while (serviceTime != 0)
        {
            (this[lineName] as ObservableCollection<Line>).Add(new Line { X1 = x1, Y1 = y1, X2 = x2, Y2 = y2 });

            //Delay Code

            x1 += 10;
            x2 += 10;
            serviceTime--;
        }
        ResetXY();
    }
```

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000)`. But you should make your method async.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan The first in first out algorithm with your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: Why not works? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Or better you use a timer.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan i am simulating fcfs scheduling algorithm for operating system.
i have 5 process.each proccess have it's own service time.
i want to draw a line for each service time of procces with 1 second delay accroding fcfs.but your suggestion draw parallel line in wrong x,y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used Devexpress MVVM Dispatcher to solve my problem:

```
    private void DrawLine(int serviceTime, string lineName)
    {
        while (serviceTime != 0)
        {
            DispatcherService.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                    (this[lineName] as ObservableCollection<Line>).Add(new Line { X1 = x1, Y1 = y1, X2 = x2, Y2 = y2 });
            });
            x1 += 10;
            x2 += 10;
            serviceTime--;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        ResetXY();
    }
```